# Overriding Default Laravel database configuration for artisan migrate commands

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

For my database (MySQL), I have two user accounts, one (`mydbuser`) for general application access with select/inset/update/delete permissions on all tables, the other (`mydbadmin`) with privilege to manage tables, etc

```
CREATE USER 'mydbadmin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'ultrasecret password';
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO 'mydbadmin'@'%';

CREATE USER 'mydbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'not quite so secure password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON mydb.* TO 'mydbuser'@'%';
```

My Laravel app is configured to use the `mydbuser` user, while `mydbadmin` is currently used for manually setting up the tables, etc.

Now, I want to start using Artisan `migrations` and `seeding` to handle creating the database for new instances of the application, but with the standard application configuration, `migrate` only has access to the lesser-privileged account, so can't actually create/drop the tables at all.

Is there a way of overriding the database user/password configured in database.php when I run

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

and other migrate commands? Some command line switch perhaps, that would allow me to specify the `mydbadmin` user and password? Or even just to point to a different database configuration setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use:

```
php artisan migrate:install --database=seconddb
```

but you need to have defined this `seconddb` connection in your `database.php` config file. Of course running this command you will only create `migrations` table, nothing more, so if you want to make standard migration you need to use:

```
php artisan migrate --database=seconddb
```

and for seeding:

```
php artisan db:seed --database=seconddb
```

Example `database.php` file configuration:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'maindb',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'pass',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),

'seconddb' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'otherdb',
    'username'  => 'user',
    'password'  => 'otherpass',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

And in case you need other information about paramters, you can always run `--help` argument for example:

```
php artisan migrate:install --help
php artisan migrate --help
```

Comment: For this to work I also had to remove connection parameters from .env file (DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME etc.), because they some how overrided those values from datatabse.php file.

Answer (score 2):

Would adding a new DB in the settings file help? Perhaps:

```
# Slightly different database connection
'mydbadmin' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'host1',
    'database'  => 'mydb',
    'username'  => 'mydbadmin',
    'password'  => 'ultrasecret password'
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

then specify that database within the CLI, e.g.

```
php artisan migrate:install --database['mydbadmin']
```