# Dynamic env-files (multiple databases) and artisan commands

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a large project which will have each customer on their own separate database. To get this to work we use a custom `.env`-loader that loads each customers `.env`by checking the customers subdomain (unique to each customer).

However, of course this doesn't work with artisan commands. For instance, when I want to migrate, I will need to migrate all databases at once. So I've set up an Artisan command that fetches the `.env`-files and loop through them and then calls the default `artisan migrate`. But it is not working as expected.

I've tried everything; for instance:

```
$dotenv = new Dotenv('/env', '.test.env');
$dotenv->overload();
```

And:

```
app()->useEnvironmentPath('/env');
app()->loadEnvironmentFrom('.test.env');
```

And even:

```
config('database.connections.mysql.database', 'test_database');
```

As soon as I run `$this->call('migrate');` the app defaults to the default `.env` and ignores all customizations at runtime. Does anyone have an idea on how I can overload the migration commands choice of  database?

*Note:* I know that I can manually setup multiple connections in `config/database.php` (for instance like: [Overriding Default Laravel database configuration for artisan migrate commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469370/overriding-default-laravel-database-configuration-for-artisan-migrate-commands)), however, image a few dozen customers and this would not be viable.

Comment: You might be interested in something I wrote not a long time ago  - https://github.com/mnabialek/laravel-multi-config/tree/develop and https://github.com/mnabialek/laravel-multi-domain/tree/develop (both are not tested yet at the moment)

Comment: Thanks for your comment; although that turned out to "semi-far" from what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole lot of issues I was able to sort it this way;

In Laravel 5 there seem to be a difference in `Config::set()`, `config('config',['key' => 'value])` and `config()-set('config', ['key' => 'value'])`.

After a lot of testing different variant we managed to get a solution this way;

```
$connection = 'connection';
$iterator = 0;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    App::useEnvironmentPath('/env');
    App::loadEnvironmentFrom('.file.env');

    // Create a new connection "on the fly"
    config()->set('database.connections.' . $connection . '_' . $iterator, [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]);

    // Call regular migration command
    $this->call('migrate', ['--force' => true, '--database' => $connection . '_' . $iterator]);

    $iterator++;
}
```

This manages to set multiple new connections to the MySQL-database, and then seed each one of them.

Thanks to *@David Allen* here for the inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar with SQLite database that were being created by the console commands, and the only way I could get the migrations to run was by creating a database config on the fly:

```
Config::set('database.connections.'.$config_key, array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path($database_name),
            'prefix'   => '',
));
```

And then I would call the migrate command:

```
  Artisan::call('migrate', [
        '--database' => $config_key,
        '--path' => 'database/offline/'.$type.'/migrations',
    ]);
```

Comment: Oh really? Hm, that very interesting – will check into it and get back. Thanks a bunch!